# ASP. Net Web API service connecting to oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to AP.Net MVC services and Trying to create a web service where we give the array of input which will connect to oracle database and return the query (the array of input needs used in the filter)result. I am trying no to use the entity data model and giving the POCO classes in Model classes.So what I tried is to create a simple controller which selectentire data from the database

```
 public class TestOraConnController : ApiController
 {
     public string Get(int id)
     {
        var strQuery = @"Select PRIO_CATEGORY_ID as PRIO,LANG_ID as LANG, REC_DATE as REC, REC_USER as RECUSER, RFCH_ID as RFCH,DESCR,COL_DESCR AS COL,ROW_DESCR as DROW,ABBR from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where REC_USER =" +id;
        OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=ABC;PASSWORD=ABCD;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=ABC");
        dbConn.Open();
        OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbConn);
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
        DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(selectResults);
        dbConn.Close();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
}
```

So the result looks

```
 "[{\"PRIO\":1,\"LANG\":1,\"REC\":\"2011-10-23T20:32:18\",\"RECUSER\":1,\"RFCH\":null,\"DESCR\":\"Internal Study\",\"COL\":\"Internal    Study\",\"DROW\":\"Internal Study\",\"ABBR\":\"Intern\"},{\"PRIO\":1,\"LANG\":2,\"REC\":\"2011-10-23T20:32:18\",\"RECUSER\":1,\"RFCH\":null,\"DESCR\":\"Internal Study\",\"COL\":\"Internal Study\",\"DROW\":\"Internal Study\",\"ABBR\":\"Intern\"},{\"PRIO\":2,\"LANG\":1,\"REC\":\"2011-10-23T20:32:31\",\"RECUSER\":1,\"RFCH\":null,\"DESCR\":\"Client Study\",\"COL\":\"Client Study\",\"DROW\":\"Client Study\",\"ABBR\":\"Client\"}]"
```

Now if I need to give the array of input parameter I am how to interate through the array of parameters to select. I understand we give the

```
 public string get( int []d)
```

But not sure how we need to change the query. Any hep is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no "ASP.NET MVC Web Services". There is ASP.NET Web API, though.

Comment: That was mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep your "strQuery" variable, you can use the IN keyword :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)
```

And [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx) method to format your Ids

```
var ints = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var ids= string.Join(",", ints.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());// "1,2,3,4,5"

var strQuery = $@"Select PRIO_CATEGORY_ID as PRIO,LANG_ID as LANG, REC_DATE    as REC, REC_USER as RECUSER, RFCH_ID as RFCH,DESCR,COL_DESCR AS COL,ROW_DESCR as DROW,ABBR from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR where REC_USER IN({ids})";
```

Comment: Thanks Joan, I am understanding the query part but really not getting how would I iterate through the array of the input parameters